# Sending Email Using apache commons mail package from android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I am developing the new app with email sending option. To send a mail I have used gmail configurations host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465 with SSL true. To send an email I have apache commons API. `OnTouch` event mail sending method will call. Whenever touch button it shows following errors,

```
Error : Could not find class 'javax.naming.InitialContext', referenced from method org.apache.commons.mail.Email.setMailSessionFromJNDI
    Warning: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 955 (Ljavax/naming/InitialContext;) in Lorg/apache/commons/mail/Email;
    Warning : org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
```

I have added  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" in my manifest file.

Can i use all java files in android ?

My email code executed correctly as a stand alone java program.

Comment: Are you wanting to send an email program-matically? example: a user presses a button and an automated email will be sent to them from the code. OR are you wanting to have the option to allow the user to send an email using there gmail app from there device? example: a user hits a button and the gmail app opens up for them to send an email?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I am doing in an app. I have an app that has its own email account that sends an email to the user when they fill out a form and press the submit button.

Important make sure you have the ***libSMTP.jar*** file referenced in your app. I am using this library for the following code. Here is the following code being used, take from it what you'd like, hope this is useful:

Imports needed:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.SMTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.SMTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.SimpleSMTPHeader;
```

Submit button to make the request to send email

```
 submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {       
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //-- Submit saves data to sqlite db, but removed that portion for this demo...


            //-- Executes an new task to send an automated email to user when they fill out a form...
            new sendEmailTask().execute();
        }
        }
    });
```

Email task to be preformed on seperate thread:

```
private class sendEmailTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {

    }

    @SuppressLint("ParserError")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        try {

            //--Note the send format is as follows: send(from, to, subject line, body message)
            send("myAppName@gmail.com",  "emailToSendTo@gmail.com", "Form Submitted",  "You submitted the form.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Send function being used:

```
public void send(String from, String to, String subject, String text) throws IOException 
{
    SMTPClient client = new SMTPClient("UTF-8");
    client.setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

    client.setRequireStartTLS(true); // requires STARTTLS
    //client.setUseStartTLS(true); // tries STARTTLS, but falls back if not supported
    client.setUseAuth(true); // use SMTP AUTH
    //client.setAuthMechanisms(authMechanisms); // sets AUTH mechanisms e.g. LOGIN

    client.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    checkReply(client);

    //--Note the following format is as follows: client.login("localhost", (...your email account being used to send email from...), (...your email accounts password ...));
    client.login("localhost", "myAppName@gmail.com", "...myAppName email account password...");
    checkReply(client);

    client.setSender(from);
    checkReply(client);
    client.addRecipient(to);
    checkReply(client);

    Writer writer = client.sendMessageData();

    if (writer != null) 
    {
        SimpleSMTPHeader header = new SimpleSMTPHeader(from, to, subject);
        writer.write(header.toString());
        writer.write(text);
        writer.close();
        client.completePendingCommand();
            checkReply(client);
    }

    client.logout();
    client.disconnect();
}
```

Check reply function being used:

```
private void checkReply(SMTPClient sc) throws IOException 
{
    if (SMTPReply.isNegativeTransient(sc.getReplyCode())) 
    {
        sc.disconnect();
        throw new IOException("Transient SMTP error " + sc.getReplyCode());
    } 
    else if (SMTPReply.isNegativePermanent(sc.getReplyCode())) 
    {
        sc.disconnect();
        throw new IOException("Permanent SMTP error " + sc.getReplyCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apache Commons Net 3.3, you can just drop the jar in your classpath and start using the AuthenticationSMTPClient : http://blog.dahanne.net/2013/06/17/sending-a-mail-in-java-and-android-with-apache-commons-net/